# Can Stoke's Law of Viscous Force be applied to freely faaling body?

Tags: air, viscosity

As air is a viscous fluid can we apply Stokes Law to freely falling bodies. By doing this we can see that the velocity of a freely falling body doesn't increase with time but it stops increasing after achieving Terminal Velocity. I've learnt from my Physics Teacher that its due to this Law that Rain Drops don't hurt us. Thus I'm curious to know if this Law can be applied to other freely falling bodies also.

Please keep in mind that I'm a high school student and not a professional so try to be simple.

Comment: Please correct any spelling errors.

Answer (score 1):

Stokes' law is valid as long as it is a laminar flow (no turbulence, no high speeds, small objects), solid material and smooth surfaces (no sharp edges, no open cavities). Air speed must be constant far from the object. Of course, for numerically precise purposes the exact form of the law is easily calculated for small droplets where the shape is spherical but it is increasingly hard to give an exact form for other shapes even if the same principle applies.